# Sorted Datatable value differs in UI gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a datatable with sorted column values and when I bind them to the gridview I'm not able to see the same order in the gridview like I have in the datatable.

Sorting event is also disable in gridview.

Can anyone please provide suggestions.

HTML:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="1" PageSize="200" AutoPostBack="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" ShowHeader="true"
                                CellSpacing="1" BackColor="#e7e7e8" BorderColor="#e7e7e8" GridLines="Both" CssClass="GridViewStyleB" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="10pt">
                                <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Position="Top" Visible="true" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#e7e7e8" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="left" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="RowStyle" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#a9a9a9" Font-Underline="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderColor="#E7E7E8" ForeColor="Black" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" BorderColor="#E7E7E8" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#e7e7e8" />
                                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
 DataTable dtColumns = FromDataTable();
 GridView1.DataSource = dtColumns;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

`dtColumns` datatable have sorted data and I when I bind them to the gridview the order changes.

Comment: Can you show how you are sorting the datatable? Because if you do not use `dtColumns.DefaultView.ToTable();` the sorting is not committed.

Comment: @VDWWD - I'm not sorting data from SQL and I need to show the value in order like how I get in the datatable. FYI, I'm not using any sorting to sort datatable and correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Then the problem lies not in the GridView or the DataTable. WIthout sorting the GridView will display the same order as the DataTable. Maybe the SQL is not sorting as you suspect or you are using a jQuery library for client side sorting also?

Comment: @VDWWD - The datatable has correct sorted rows and I just need to show the same in the gridview. The datatable already has sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a breakpoint at GridView1.DataSource = dtColumns, and inspect the dtColumns object, can you confirm the sort order of the rows?  What is the underlying query used to select the data?  If it's from a single table, what data type is the primary key?

I think if you check those things, you will find your answer, but if not, you should update your post to include that stuff :)

**EDIT**

Here is something you can try to force the sort, after you perform the databinding:

```
GridView1.Sort("column name", System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: dtColumns datatable has correct sorted data and I just need to show the same order in the gridview. I am using SQL to sort the records.

Comment: can you show the markup in your ASPX page that you are using to declare the gridview?

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anything inside of your onSorting or onRowDataBound methods?  Also, if you create a new datagrid with bare minimum properties set (just an ID, runat=server, and autogenerate columns) do you get anything different?

Comment: Both onSorting or onRowDataBound  methods doesn't have any codes inside them. I also tried with an ID, runat=server and autogenerate columns and still the same.

Comment: ok, how about this :)  rather than looking at the data in a grid... for testing purposes, loop over the datatable and just response.write out the values for each row.  are they written out in order?  Also, what if, rather than autogenerate columns, you specify each column (using boudnColumns) ?